# Blocking and non-blocking modes in PHP Streams

Tags: php, stream

I am studying for the PHP 5 Certification exam. This function was mentioned in the practice exams.

function [stream_set_blocking](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php)():

> Sets blocking or non-blocking mode on
>   a stream.
>
> This function works for any stream
>   that supports non-blocking mode
>   (currently, regular files and socket
>   streams).

From both a high-level and low-level perspective, how do blocking mode and non-blocking mode streams behave in PHP? What i a socket stream and a non-socket stream? Examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The blocking/non-blocking mode says if the fread/fwrite functions will return immediately. When in `non-blocking mode`, they will return **any available data**. If no data can be read at the time the function is invoked, then none will be returned. Such streams are typicalled polled in a loop.

In `blocking mode` however, the function will always **wait** (and therefore block your programs execution) until it can satisfy the complete read request. If you ask to read 1MB from a network socket, the function will not return until it has received 1MB to pass on.

I think Wikipedia covers it quite well:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Blocking_vs._non-blocking_mode

It mostly has effect on networked file/stream sources. For local filesystems the operating system will always read the desired length of data. PHP also has [stream wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-set-option.php), which can handle that option at their discretion (there's no reliable general rule).

For more low-level details, visit the manpages of fnctl(2) or socket(2) or
 http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html